# RSA Encryption after publishing the web site

Tags: asp.net, web, cryptography, rsa, publishing

I have a web site uses RSA for encrypt some data. when i run it on local host, the RSA function works correctly. But after publishing my web site the function gives me an error.
the function call is

```
Cryptography encryptor = new Cryptography();
string pkpath = Server.MapPath("publickey.xml");
byte[] RSAcipher = encryptor.RSAEncryptData(RSAplain, pkpath);
```

and the RSAEncryptData() function code is

```
 public  void AssignParameter()
    {
        const int PROVIDER_RSA_FULL = 1;
        const string CONTAINER_NAME = "SpiderContainer";
        CspParameters cspParams;
        cspParams = new CspParameters(PROVIDER_RSA_FULL);
        cspParams.KeyContainerName = CONTAINER_NAME;
        cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
        cspParams.ProviderName = "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider";
        rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
    }

    public  byte[] RSAEncryptData(byte[] data2Encrypt,string pkpath)
    {
        AssignParameter();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@pkpath);
        string publicOnlyKeyXML = reader.ReadToEnd();
        rsa.FromXmlString(publicOnlyKeyXML);
        reader.Close();

        //read plaintext, encrypt it to ciphertext

        //byte[] plainbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data2Encrypt);
        byte[] cipherbytes = rsa.Encrypt(data2Encrypt, false);

        //return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherbytes);
        return cipherbytes;
    }

  public  byte[] RSADecryptData(byte[] data2Decrypt,string prpath)
    {
        AssignParameter();

        //byte[] getpassword = Convert.FromBase64String(data2Decrypt);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@prpath);
        string publicPrivateKeyXML = reader.ReadToEnd();
        rsa.FromXmlString(publicPrivateKeyXML);
        reader.Close();

        //read ciphertext, decrypt it to plaintext
        byte[] plain = rsa.Decrypt(data2Decrypt, false);
        //return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plain);
        return plain;

    }
```

the stack trace of the error is
[Error stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmfz8.png)

Comment: Why are you instantiating a provider (with the same name) multiple times? Couldn't you perform `AssignParameter` (terrible name for a method) just once?

Comment: I'm really wondering if the name should be Microsoft Strong Cryptography Provider or if it should be present at all. I'm trying to figure out if it is the name of the CSP to be created or one that is already present. What happens if you leave it out?

Comment: I perform `AssignParameter` just once at encryption and at decryption, @MaartenBodewes  Are you mean, i don't need to assign a provider name?